# Apply Grid-Overlay to Image and Video

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following issue:

- I want to add an overlay to my videos and images.
- The overlay is based on an PNG-Pixel.
- I want to cover the whole width and height of the images and cideos by repeating the PNG-Pixel

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljBrB.png <- this is the pixel

Here is an Example for the result: https://theuprisingcreative.com/video/

```css
        * {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
        
        .row {
            clear: both;
        }
        
        .spalten-6 {
            width: 49.99992%;
        }

        .spalten-12 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .spalten-6,  .spalten-12 
        { float:left;} 
   
        .img-box img {
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .img-box {
            border-left: 2px solid white;
            border-top: 2px solid white;
        }
        

#video-container {
    position: relative;
    height:300px
}
#video-container {
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;

}
video#bgVid {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    background: url('http://ewallpaperhub.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/nature-wallpaper-3.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: 1s opacity;
}
video#bgVid.fillWidth {
    width: 100%;
   position:relative
}
```

```html
<div id="video-container">
<video id="bgVid" loop class="fillWidth" autoplay>
<source src=http://bigcom.com/assets/2014/08/iChooseB.mp4 type=video/mp4>
</video> 
</div>
  
<div id="underneath">   
<p style="color:#000">content underneath</p>
    </div>

   <div class="row">
   <div class="spalten-6">
      <div class="img-box">
     <img src="Images/fargo-jamie-lee-video-clip.png" alt="">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="spalten-6">
       <div class="img-box">
       <div class="overlay">
     <img src="Images/la-bomba-video-clip.jpg" alt="">
       </div>
       </div>
   </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to achieve the desired result using a [CSS gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) background on a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) for the element `#video-container`.

For example, if I add:

```
background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0), linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0), transparent;
```

and its prefixed versions to `#video-container:after`, I get the following working example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  clear: both;
}

.spalten-6 {
  width: 49.99992%;
}

.spalten-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

.spalten-6,
.spalten-12 {
  float: left;
}

.img-box img {
  width: 100%;
}

.img-box {
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  position:relative
}

#video-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px
}

#video-container {
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative; font-size:0;
}

#video-container:after, .img-box:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0), transparent;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0), -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0), transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0), linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0), transparent;
  -webkit-background-size: 1px 1px;
  background-size: 1px 4px;
}

video#bgVid {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url('http://ewallpaperhub.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/nature-wallpaper-3.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 1s opacity;
}

video#bgVid.fillWidth {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<div id="video-container">
  <video id="bgVid" loop class="fillWidth" autoplay>
<source src=http://bigcom.com/assets/2014/08/iChooseB.mp4 type=video/mp4>
</video>
</div>

<div id="underneath">
  <p style="color:#000">content underneath</p>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="spalten-6">
    <div class="img-box">
      <img src="http://img.clubic.com/00466352-photo-cadre-philips-affichage-16-9.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spalten-6">
    <div class="img-box">
      <div class="overlay">
        <img src="http://www.photographycorner.com/galleries/data/2882/aspect4.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can control the "pixel" size and color using the property `background-size` on the pseudo-element `#video-container:after`. You can also control the opacity for the entire grid and adjust it to your liking without affecting the video.

Comment: Thanks, Mate. Do you have an idea how am I able to add this overlay to the "img-box" below?

Comment: No problem @PeterPilz I edited the answer to add the overlay to `.img-box` as well. If there are any other elements that you need to add the overlay to, all you need is to set the element to `position:relative` and add the background to one of its pseudo-elements

Answer (score 0):

```
#video-container::after {
    content: "";
    height: 165%;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljBrB.png) 0px 0px repeat rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
```